# Dsquery nested groups

Tags: active-directory, dsquery

How would I write a dsquery to get a list of all the members of a d-list, expanding any nested groups to get the members of those groups?

I've written this:

```
dsquery * -filter "(&(memberOf=cn=...))" -r -limit 0 -attr 
CUSTOMFIELD sAMAccountName displayName > export.txt
```

but returns nested d-lists and I want to expand these.

I then tried this:

```
dsquery group -samid "NAME | dsget group -members -expand > export.txt
```

But this just lists the OU of each member and I want to get the Account Name and a custom field returned.

Is there any way, either of chosing which fields to return from dsget or to epxand dsquery to show nested group membership?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

See "dsget group /?" for an example.

dsget group "CN=DL1,OU=Whatever,DC=Domain,DC=Com" -members -expand

The above should work. But it will spit nested DL names along with members of them.