# Piping DSQUERY commands together

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, command-line-interface, dsquery

Can DSQUERY commands be piped together?

eg to return a list of users in each of the groups found within the 'Builtin' container?

`dsquery groups "cn=Builtin,dc=domain,dc=company" | dsquery groups "cn=%builtingroups%cn=Builtin,dc=domain,dc=company" -members >>usergroups.txt`

Where `%builtingroups%` is the result of the first query (ie a list of groups)

Thanks!

Comment: I think [this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/212477/dsquery-nested-groups) is similar but doesn't return the result i'm looking for (ie a user list within every group contained per container)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %a in (`dsquery group "cn=Builtin,dc=domain,dc=company"`) do echo ===%a members: >> members.txt && dsget group %a -members >> members.txt
```

Comment: thanks, i'll try it later! Care to explain what each part does? I can partly figure it out myself... :)

Comment: Well, it gets list of groups with "dsquery group", then it goes through that list and for each line calls dsget to pick members. "echo ... &&" is just to make output more readable so you can omit that. Type "for /?" for usebackq and delims explanation. It will be more clear when you look at it running.

Comment: `dsquery failed:A referral was returned from the server.` Any ideas to troubleshoot?

Comment: try dsquery alone: dsquery group "cn=Builtin,dc=domain,dc=company", it is usually a typing error

Comment: You did change dc=domain,dc=company with your domain data :) ?

Comment: Errrr, i'll check! Might be my error, sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the referral was for a query for a user in a Trusting Domain from a Workstation in the Trusted domain.
(One way trust Trusting->Trusted)

From `WKS.TRUSTED.DOM`

```
dsquery user "DC=TRUSTING,DC=DOM" -samid <account in Trusting.dom>
dsquery failed:A referral was returned from the server.
```

Why? Because the Domain Controllers for Trusting.com are all behind a firewall and unreachable.

Additional diagnostic:

```
dsquery user "DC=TRUSTING,DC=DOM" -samid <account in Trusting.dom> -s DC1.Trusted.dom
dsquery failed:The server is not operational.
```

When a VPN from the network for WKS.Trusted.DOM is established to the network for Trusting.DOM is established, the query succeeds just fine.

Comment: You've posted this as an answer to the original question. Perhaps it is more suited as a comment.